# Initializing gradle error using flutter

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

I want to create and run my first [flutter](https://flutter.io/) app, using Android Studio on Windows 10. I followed the instructions [here](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/) and [here](https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/), but when I create a new flutter project and click run (with my mobile connected), I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on <My Mobile> in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: Exit code 1 from: <app_folder>\android\gradlew.bat -v:

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_152-release (JetBrains s.r.o 25.152-b02)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

When I run `flutter doctor` I get no issues. The solutions I found online have not worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the whole error log?

Comment: This is the whole error I see in android studio.